# How to obtain line and/or column from parsed java source from Eclipse JDT Parser from all nodes?

Tags: java, eclipse, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I've been playing for quite a while now with ASTs and was trying to get the line and column information associated to a given node parsed on this plugin from eclipse. According to the documented api [here](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/class-use/ASTVisitor.html) I found that the method `getStartPosition()` can give me the position on the characters of the file that was parsed, but this is not what I wanted.

I went on the [CompilationUnit class api documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/ASTVisitor.html) to find out the methods `getLineNumber(int position)` and `getColumnNumber(int position)` which from my understanding can do the trick. the `position` paramater is nothing less than what the `getStartPosition()` method returns, by doing `node.getStartPosition()`.

Now, the problem is the two methods that get line and column on source file doesn't seems to be available for all nodes. For instance, the [method declaration nodes](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/MethodDeclaration.html) don't have them!

How can I get such information on all the tree? I know this is not impossible since I was able to use parsers for other languages that for **every** ast node had a line and column associated with it. In fact, I believe [javaparser](http://code.google.com/p/javaparser/) is one of them for java, since the class contains attributes for line and column hardcoded. Seeing Eclipse JDT seemed to me much more robust to me and being there for quite a while, I would be surprised that such information would not be possible to acquire.

**Edit:** Again, the problem is obtaining the line number from things different of the compilation unit that only appears on the root:

```
<type 'org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnit'>
1
<type 'org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.TypeDeclaration'>
<type 'org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.Javadoc'>
<type 'org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.TagElement'>
<type 'org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.TextElement'>
<type 'org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.TextElement'>
<type 'org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.TextElement'>
<type 'org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.TextElement'>
<type 'org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.TextElement'>
<type 'org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.TextElement'>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For posterity, I'm reposting the answer I posted on the jdt-core-dev mailing list. (My answer is not very different from Ryan's suggestion above)

Hi Carlos,

You're correct about the CompilationUnit.getLineNumber(int) method. You use it as follows:

`int lineNumber = compilationUnit.getLineNumber(node.getStartPosition()) - 1;`

However, I don't understand where you're stuck. Why do you need the getLineNumber(..) defined for MethodDeclaration? All you have to do is to find the method declaration node, then find out the corresponding CompilationUnit for it using the code below, and then use the above line of code to find the line number. Am I missing something here?

```
ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3); // or JLS_4 for java 7 and above

parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
parser.setSource(source); // give your java source here as char array
parser.setResolveBindings(true);

CompilationUnit compilationUnit = parser.createAST(null);
```

Cheers!
Ayush

Comment: Thank you I wasn't realizing that the CU was associated with a given java file and thus it would be reasonable for it to have the information of the line position for a node of a ast that pertained to that file. I was more used to the mental model each node would have the associated line and column it belonged because that was the only model I've seen around. It all boils down to the way of set the class responsibilities and this new one wasn't make sense. Now everything runs and works. I up vote and set yours as answered since I came to realize it from your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a running program in front of me, but based on the documentation you linked to above and the source code at Eclipse, it appears that you can get the `CompilationUnit` for the `ASTNode` by calling `getRoot()` and casting it to `CompilationUnit`. Alternatively, it appears from the `ASTParser` [javadoc](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/ASTParser.html) and an example at [ibm](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ast/), that `ASTParser.createAST(IProgressMonitor)` nearly always returns a `CompilationUnit` which represents the source that you are parsing.

After you have a `CompilationUnit` named `root`, you should then be able to use the `root.getLineNumber(node.getStartPosition())` and `root.getColumnNumber(node.getStartPosition())` methods.

```
final ASTParser p = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
p.setSource(source);
final CompilationUnit root = (CompilationUnit) p.createAST(null);
// stuff happens
final ASTNode node = //get a node

final int line = root.getLineNumber(node.getStartPosition());
final int column = root.getColumnNumber(node.getStartPosition());
System.out.println("Node started at (" + line + ", " + column + ")";
```

Comment: Thank you, I up voted the answer since its also coherent as well. Voted the other as final answer because it helped me realize the difference on my mental model on how to approach the problem. Noted that on the comment of the other answer.